# Edit ParagraphFormat of a specific ParagraphStyle in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to programmatically change some options under ParagraphFormat for text with a specified ParagraphStyle (e.g. "Normal" style). For that purpose I use the following condition:

```
If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style = wdStyleNormal Then
```

My macro is executed, but no changes happen. Without this condition the changes are done to each and every paragraph in the document.

What an I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `wdStyleNormal` this way only works when you want to assign a built-in style to the paragraph:

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style = wdStyleNormal
```

When you read the style back from the property, you get the `Style` object that describes the style, not the constant you set. If you want to check if this style is a certain style, you need to examine it's `NameLocal`. The problem is, the name is different in different languages, so you could do something like this:

```
If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style.NameLocal = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).NameLocal Then
```

Comment: Works as intended. Marked your reply as answer. Thank you!